# How to check for a "between 23:00 and 6:30" condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-arrow

I would like to check with `arrow`<sup>(*)</sup> whether the current time is between 23:00 and 6:30.

I currently use naive checks in the code below but was wondering whether there is an `arrow` native construction available

```
import arrow

def check(now):
    if now.hour >= 23 or now.hour < 6 or (now.hour == 6 and now.minute <= 30):
        print("we are between 23:00 and 6:30 the next day")
    else:
        print("we are outside the range")

#out
now = arrow.get('2013-05-05 12:30:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
check(now)

# in
now = arrow.get('2013-05-05 23:30:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
check(now)

# in
now = arrow.get('2013-05-06 01:30:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
check(now)

# in
now = arrow.get('2013-05-06 05:45:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
check(now)

# out
now = arrow.get('2013-05-06 07:30:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
check(now)
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> I happily use `arrow` for years but if the solution is more straightforward with another package (`dolorean` or another one similar I forgot the name of) it is fine as well

Comment: Your current code isn't correct, what if it's 5.45?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: you are right, thanks. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with a default `datetime` python's library, but please keep in mind that you have to stick with a timezone, I would recommend using UTC by calling `datetime.utcnow` or `datetime.now` if you need local time. Here is an example:

```
In [12]: from datetime import datetime
In [13]: now = datetime.utcnow()
In [14]: now.hour
Out[14]: 16
In [15]: 6 < now.hour < 23
Out[15]: True
```

PS. If `datetime` is not an option by some reason, you can go with `arrow.utcnow()` or same localized `arrow.now()` variant.

Comment: Thanks, there is still the problem of the 30 minutes after 6 (I am actually looking for the inverse check than in your code, but it does not matter - it is just a flip of the signs)